# Replace nth element of list with regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a file with lists of strings separated by semicolons, like this one:

```
aaaa;bbb;ccccccc;dd;  
eeee;fff;ggggggg;hh;  
iiii;jjj;kkkkkkk;ll;
```

and am looking for a regex expression to replace the nth element of every line (using Notepad++ v6.8.3, regex engine mostly following the Perl syntax). I believe this expression

```
^([^\;]*\;){n}([^;]*)
```

with n being a number will capture everything until the nth semicolon. What do I need to replace it with to change only the nth entry of every line?

As an example: If n=3, I would like a regex and the replacement to obtain

```
aaaa;bbb;xxxxxxx;dd;  
eeee;fff;xxxxxxx;hh;  
iiii;jjj;xxxxxxx;ll;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search:

```
^((?:[^;]*;){2})([^;]*;)([^;]*)
```

Replace:

```
\1xxxxxx;\3
```

#### What I changed:

- made the group with the quantifier non capturing (`?:`) and added a capture group around it to capture everything at once
- changed `n` to `n-1` and copied the inner group `([^;]*;)` to capture the n<sup>th</sup> group separately
- removed some superfluous escaping